# Hide the website link in the usercard

Tags: support, hyperlinks, user-card

I'm wondering if is there a way to hide/remove the *Website link* from my own *usercard* when it's expanded, keeping the link itself visible when someone visits my profile.

Comment: put it as part of your profile instead of "website"?

Comment: Adding on to what Patrice said, upon moving it into your "About Me" section, you'll want to make sure it doesn't show up, which you can do with `<!-- summary: [text you want to show up in the expanded card] -->` (Pulled from the [privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) the user card is mentioned on.) Other than that, I don't think there is a way to do what you wish currently. (At least I can't currently find a way via searches.)

Comment: @Patrice effectively... so obvious! :-\ but I was wondering if there were some hiding-option available, like the *summary* in the *About me* section

Comment: @fantaghirocco not that I know of :P I was going for the easy workaround :p

Comment: Thank you all; a combination of the two seems the way to go